# Cannot save data to .txt (Java OOP console application)

Tags: java, oop, netbeans, console-application

So basically i'm developing simple library management system console app using Java on NetBeans IDE. I wanted to save book data to .txt but it seems like i made a some logical error here or something. I'm a newbie, please help.

So I made a class called "Book"

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        public int bookId;
        public String bookTitle, author,Description, alley;

        public Book(){}
        public Book(int bookid, String booktitle, String Author, String desc, String Alley)
        {
            bookId = bookid;bookTitle=booktitle;author=Author;Description=desc;alley=Alley;
        }
        public int getbookID()
        {return bookId;}
        public String getBookTitle()
        {return bookTitle;}
        public String getAuthor()
        {return author;}
        public String getDescription()
        {return Description;}
        public String getAlley()
        {return alley;}

        public void setbookID(int bid)
        {bookId = bid;}
        public void setbookTitle(String bt)
        {bookTitle = bt;}
        public void setbookAuthor(String a)
        {author = a;}
        public void setDescription(String Desc)
        {Description = Desc;}
        public void setAlley(String alleY)
        {alley = alleY;}

        public String ToString()
        {
            return bookId + " " + bookTitle + " " + author + " " + Description + " " + alley;
        }

        public void WriteToTxt()
        {
            try
            {
                File f = new File("book.txt");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true); //set to True to append more
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
                pw.write(this.toString());
                pw.write("/n");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

and I made a class Administrator that has add book method

```
public void addNewBook()
    {
         int bid;
         String bookTitle, Author, Description, alley;
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Book ID: ");
        bid = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Book Title: ");
        bookTitle = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Book Author: ");
        Author = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Book Description: ");
        Description = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Book Alley: ");
        alley = scan.next();

        Book b = new Book(bid, bookTitle, Author, Description, alley);
        b.WriteToTxt();

    }
```

It successfully created the txt file but the content isn't what expected.

```
lmsconsole.Book@7d4991ad/n
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a silly typo in your `ToString` method. The correct name is `toString` (methods *always* begin with lowercase letters in Java).

To write a new line you can use `println()` or simply write the `"\n"` char (note that escaped chars use a *backslash*).

Finally, always add a `@Override` annotation (above the method) to be extra sure you are *overriding* the correct method from now on.

---

By the way, as matter of coding style, you also might consider using `this` when assigning `Book` fields in the constructor:

```
this.bookId = bookId;
this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
...
```

which would enable safer code and better parameters names in your constructor, improving code readability.

Comment: Sorted. Thanks bro!

Comment: @Irfan You are welcome! If my answer satisfied your needs, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer to also benefit future coders. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I have noticed :

```
public String ToString()
```

What you want to accomplish can't be achieved through this method, it should be **toString**

Also you have to follow @Paulos answer as well

Answer (score 0):

you have wrote definiton for ToString() instead of toString()

you used /n instead of \n

correcting the above mentioned mistakes should do the trick.